Getting the rapid rate override using THINC API
I didnt find any method on Okuma SDK (C#) to retrieve the rapid rate override.
I looked into axis class but there is nothing which returns this data.
Is it stored on a common variable?
Here is the assembly I use: Okuma.CLDATAPI
Thanks,
Avichai
